# How to include relations in Rails with Grape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape

In My Grape app I want to change return (in response) number of used `campaign_codes` and all `campaign_codes` for each campaign. To do so I need to return also the relationship objects. Here is my serializer:

```
module V1
  module AdminPanel
    module Serializers
      class CampaignSerializer
        include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer

        attributes :total_campaign_codes_amount, :used_campaign_codes_amount

        attribute :total_campaign_codes_amount do |campaign|
          campaign.campaign_codes.count
        end

        attribute :used_campaign_codes_amount do |campaign|
          campaign.campaign_codes.where(state: 'used').count
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But with this code I receive an error:

> ArgumentError (campaign_codes is not specified as a relationship on V1::AdminPanel::Serializers::CampaignSerializer)

If I add `has_many :campaign_codes` it will worked but in additional I'm returning all `campaign_codes` which is not what I want to.

Is there any chance to `include` somewhere this `campaign_codes` without getting a response with all codes?

Comment: Have never used this, looking the [readme](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi#conditional-relationships) though, it appears you can use the `fields` option when you instantiate the serializer (see the section on  "Sparse Fieldsets")